# How to use superagent to send a FormData object

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, form-data

I am doing an API request follow by another one to a different server to which I need to pass a file.

Doing the first one is nice and easy. It looks something like this:

```
if (myFile) {
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('myFile', myFile, myFile.name)
    myFile = data
  }

isomorphicFetch(`${MY_ENDPOINT}`, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        body: myFile
      })
```

Now, in the server side, I need to pass this into another server. Which I am using superagent for. However I seem to be losing the file in the process. Here is what the code currently looks like:

```
const fileField = Object.keys(data).pop()
if (fileField === 'myFile') {
  res = await request
    .patch(`${MY_OTHER_ENDPOINT}`)
    .send(data)
    .query(query)
}
```

Take note that `data` is the body of the previous request, and the `FormData` object is displayed as an empty object, so I am not sure what to do from here.

On my other server, my file comes back as `undefined`, however if I do the request straight from the client, it goes through as expected. So how can I forward the FormData object from one server app to the other?

Answer (score 1):

Files are typically posted to servers as part of a Multipart request.

Superagent supports multipart requests like so:

```
request
  .post('/upload')
  .attach('image1', 'path/to/felix.jpeg')
  .attach('image2', imageBuffer, 'luna.jpeg')
  .field('caption', 'My cats')
  .then(callback);
```

Additional information can be found in their documentation:
[Superagent Docs - Multipart requests](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests)

Specific to your example, you want to make sure that your server is receiving the file and then using the ***attach*** function to put the file in your request.

Comment: So basically in the body of my isomorphicFetch from the client I should send the path and name instead of the `FormData` object?